# How does MongoDB pick a first property it will sort by?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

```
db.numbers.find().sort( { a : 1, b : 1, c : 1 })
```

If I execute this command MongoDB will sort numbers collection by property 'a', if 'a' is the same on two docs it will sort them by 'b' property, if that is the same too it will go on to 'c'. I hope I got that right, correct me if not.
But how does it pick 'a' property as first when it is just a JS object? Does it iterate over sorting object properties using for(var propr in ...) and whichever is first is also first to be sorted by?

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, but it does not contain anything that would indicate an answer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort

Comment: The JS object must be ordered, this is most evident in python whereby you must use something other than dicts since dicts are not ordered. The object will be ordered by declaration, even in mongo console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, MongoDB doesn't use JSON, is uses BSON.  While JSON is technically un-ordered, BSON, (per the [specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)) is ordered.   This is how MongoDB knows that in {a:1, b:1, c:1} that the keys are ordered "a,b,c": the underlying implementation is ordered as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sammaye posted above in the comments, the JavaScript dictionary must be created with key priority in mind.

Hence, if you do something like this:

```
db.numbers.find().sort({
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1
});
```

your results will be sorted first by `a`, then by `b`, then by `c`.

If you do this, however:

```
db.numbers.find().sort({
    c: 1,
    a: 1,
    b: 1
});
```

your results will be sorted first by `c`, then by `a`, then by `b`.

Answer (score 0):

By using those keys you mentioned:

```
db.numbers.find().sort({
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1
});
```

MongoDB sorts with property a, b, and then c.

Basically, MongoDB scans from the beginning of the datafile (CMIIW). Hence, if MongoDB finds two or more documents with the same keys as yours (a,b, and c), it prints the first document found in the datafile first.